# How do I show multiple values from an entity reference?

Tags: views

I have a content *A* that uses reference from users. Users, basically, have more than a content *A*.
I have view that shows users and adds a relationship from the field used in content *A*. I added a field to show the title of content *A* related to the user.

I can show it, but if users have more than one content *a*, it shows multiple rows for the same users, instead of showing a single row listing all the referenced content *A*.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Under multiple field settings, chekmark display all values in the same row

[image]

Comment: i don't have that option in my field setting, so basically.. when i add the realtionship from content "a" field (which have reference to user) to view that list user.. it just create new row instead..

i event dont add field that inside content "a" which have relationship to user for my view...

so what i'm missing ?

Comment: this is the capture image --> https://i.ibb.co/8jCMhkZ/Screen-Shot-2019-11-13-at-14-06-46.png

Comment: @RenaldiYulvianda Add the reference field rather than title